# Set Style of GridLines in BarChart

Tags: plotting, charts

With

```
values = RandomInteger[{10}, 5]
```

this works:

```
    BarChart[values,
     BarOrigin -> Left,
     ChartStyle -> Orange,
     ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle",
     ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["a", "e"],
     GridLines -> {{Mean@values}, None}
 ]
```

and delivers:

[image]

Now I want the line for the mean in style "Thick". Normally one uses the pair {value, style}, e.g. (from the documentation:

```
        Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10},GridLines -> {{{Pi, Dashed}, 
        {2 Pi, Thick}}, {{-1,Orange}, -.5, .5, {1, Orange}}}]
```

but not with BarChart. For the following I get an error message "A line specification in the value of GridLines should be of the form: number or {number, style}."

```
BarChart[values,
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartStyle -> Orange,
 ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle",
 ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["a", "e"],
 GridLines -> {{Mean@values, Thick}, None}
 ]
```

Can anyone help me out and get the GridLine in Thick style?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLinesStyle.html

Comment: @JasonB.: I know, but this sets the overall style, not for one line

Answer (score 1):

```
       BarChart[values, BarOrigin -> Left, ChartStyle -> Orange, 
       ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", 
      ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["a", "e"], 
        GridLines -> {{Mean@values}, None}, 
        GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thick]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a set of `{}` around your value/style list.  The gridlines specifications should be of the form

```
GridLines -> {{{line1x,style1x},{line2x,style2x}}, yGridLines}
```

So this is what you need:

```
BarChart[values,
    BarOrigin -> Left, ChartStyle -> Orange, ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle",
    ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["a", "e"],
    GridLines -> {{{Mean[values], Thick}}, None}
]
```

Comment: Thank! I've overseen this. Thank you very much.